# Identify each item with least function

Tags: algorithm

Give you a set of items and a set of functions. Each function can divide those items into two parts. We say a subset of those functions can identify each item, if any two items will be separate into different parts in at least one function in this subset. Try to build a algorithm that can find a smallest subset of functions that can identify each item.

We can travel across every subset of those functions, and test if it can identify each items, and select the smallest one. But if there is a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: Do you need the best, or is a decent greesy solution good enough?

Comment: Do you know anything else about the functions? E.g., if each function divides a set of n items into subsets of size 1 and size (n-1) then you can't do better than linear, whereas if each function divided every set of n items into approximately equal halves then you have log time.

Comment: The functions are common, some of them may divided the set into two equal part, but some may put all items into one part and left the other part empty. I want a algorithm that can find the really smallest subset of the functions.